# SQL Insert value into view from trigger

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have my **view** `Registrations(idnr, code, status)` and I created a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER Register_trigger
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Registrations
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE Register_function();
```

And my **function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION Register_function() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    BEGIN
IF (statement) THEN
   -- insert into Registrations view here
ENDIF
RETURN NEW;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsqlp;
```

Since my trigger goes off everytime I insert into my view it will create an infinite loop. My task is to avoid inserting directly into tables. Is there another way to insert values from a trigger into a view without causing this infinite loop?

In this **documentation:** https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE

They only insert values into tables. I have tried to insert directly from the trigger but that caused an infinite insert loop.

Comment: An "Instead of" trigger would NOT insert into the view. Instead it  inserts into the underlying table of the view.

Comment: @Belayer, so I should have a table I am inserting to in an "instead of" trigger? Is this used in SQL to prevent SQL-injections and such or is there a different approach to inserting values in a view via a trigger?

Comment: Yes, a view is just s stored SQL statement.  If the data for the view is persisted (other option is just generated) then there must be a table(s) for that SQL. That table(s) is what the instead of trigger updates.